# How to display 3 2 1 text in the center of the screen in transparency mode

Tags: android, android-layout

First of all, I am new to android development and searched everywhere but didn't get any solution to my problem. So please don't rate this post negative.

I am making a small game application in which I want to display 3 2 1 at the center of the screen in bixtext, and it should come in transparency mode such that the activity below the 
3 2 1 text should be visible and when it reaches 1 then the activity should start like in any game.

Comment: What do u mean by:  "when it reaches 1"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `TextView` to your xml layout (`textView123` here) and that wouldn't be so hard to go:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView123);
final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(3);
final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(n.get()));
                if(n.getAndDecrement() >= 1 )
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                else {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // start the game
                }
            }
        };
handler.postDelayed(counter, 1000);
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks I think it would work,  sorry power cut so can't really try it right now, can you provide me any guide for handler and adapter I'm not good at them and I think we need them a lot while programming in android.

Comment: Google it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html,

Comment: Hey buddy could you please help me with this AtomicInteger, I have never used it...So please tell me its exact purpose and where should we use it?

Comment: You can't access the value of a variable in an inner class or inner method ( the 'run()' here) until you define it as 'final' and once you define a variable as 'final' you can't change its value after the first assignment (initialization), so in order to change the value of a variable in an inner class, you should perform an atomic operation which does not have that limitation

Comment: Hey when I am using it in onCreate getting this error : Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead

I have initialized button, this is the code which I am using

Comment: final TextView TvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvCounter);
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
 final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(3);
 final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TvCounter.setText(Integer.toString(n.get()));
            if(n.getAndDecrement() >= 1 )
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            else {
                TvCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // start the game
            }
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(counter, 1000);

Comment: The code run without the problem, just sure to run your view codes (code manipulating your views) after "setContentView"

Comment: If I am creating the methods in onCreate method then its working ...after or before onCreate its giving error, so do I have to call this in onCreate method?

Comment: Working now but in the else part I am getting error, I am using :

Intent Calculate = new Intent(this, Calculation.class);
                      startActivity(Calculate);

in else part and getting error:

The constructor Intent(new Runnable(){}, Class<Calculation>) is undefined

Comment: That's because the first parameter 'this' inside a Runnable does not refer to your activity so you must define a "final Context ThisContext = this;" outside of Runnable and use ThisContext instead of this

Answer (score 0):

As for making the Countdown activity transparent - `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null)`.

What you can do is when you launch the timer to countdown, when it finishes the 1 countdown, create a transition to the next activity with a fade-in transition.

Though i don't understand why you don't use a frameLayout and the countdown timer as just a view on the same activity. That would certainly be a better approach.